# How to get Org-mode live buffer export?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Anyway to have an org-mode doc open in 1 pane and a live buffer export in a second pane?

Comment: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9894/2441 A function to export to LaTeX as the buffer is saved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no generic way of doing it. However, if HTML preview is good enough for you, there is [org-preview-html](https://github.com/lujun9972/org-preview-html) that updates on save.